# WPF Tile Background with png image and solid color

Tags: c#, wpf, background, tile

I have a code like this

```
<Viewbox Grid.Row="1">
  <controls:Tile Name="tileInvoice" Click="tileInvoice_Click" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ToolTip="{x:Static resx:omniLang.Invoice}">
    <controls:Tile.Background>
      <ImageBrush ImageSource="Resources/invoice.png" Stretch="Uniform"/>
    </controls:Tile.Background>
    <TextBlock Name="headerInvoice" Text="{x:Static resx:omniLang.Invoice}" FontSize="22" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,100,0,0" />
  </controls:Tile>
</Viewbox>
```

I would love to use solid color for background, still using png image on it. I'm so out of the ideas already. Should I use VisualBrush to achieve this?

Comment: Very similar question... http://stackoverflow.com/a/14085305/1706610

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, a `Background` property can only have one value, so you simply can't set two backgrounds to the same property. However, there is nothing to stop you from putting your control into a container control and setting the `Background` property of that as well:

```
<Viewbox Grid.Row="1">
    <Grid Background="Red"> <!-- Set your solid colour here -->
        <controls:Tile Name="tileInvoice" Click="tileInvoice_Click" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ToolTip="{x:Static resx:omniLang.Invoice}">
            <controls:Tile.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Resources/invoice.png" Stretch="Uniform"/>
            </controls:Tile.Background>
            <TextBlock Name="headerInvoice" Text="{x:Static resx:omniLang.Invoice}" FontSize="22" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,100,0,0" />
        </controls:Tile>
    </Grid>
</Viewbox>
```