# How to Change XAML Grid Background

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, background, imagebrush

I have the following `XAML` code to create a Windows Universal App:

```
<Page
x:Class="CalculationQuizzer.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:CalculationQuizzer"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Image Source="ms-appx:///Images/kingscross.jpg" Opacity=".3" Stretch="Fill"></Image>
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock Text="Calculation Quizzer" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="4" FontSize="16"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Name="questionTextBlock" Text="" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="4"></TextBlock>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="4">
            <TextBox Name="answerTextBox" Width="100" Margin="4" TextAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
            <Button Content="Check Answer" Name="checkAnswerButton" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Margin="4" Click="checkAnswerButton_Click" ></Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <Button Content="Next Question" Name="getNextQuestionButton" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Margin="4" Click="getNextQuestionButton_Click" ></Button>
        <TextBlock Name="resultTextBlock" Text="" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="4"></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
    <MediaElement Name="soundMediaElement"></MediaElement>
</Grid>
```

As you can see the Grid uses an Image called `kingscross.jpg` for it's background. I'm trying to make it so that the click on button `Next Answer` will cause Grid background to change to an Image called `SKV_8915_s.jpg`.

Here is a code behind the `XAML`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace CalculationQuizzer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        IQuizObject activeQuiz;

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            activeQuiz = new AdditionQuizObject();
            questionTextBlock.Text = activeQuiz.GetQuestion();
        }

        private void getNextQuestionButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            activeQuiz.NextQuestion();
            questionTextBlock.Text = activeQuiz.GetQuestion();
            answerTextBox.Text = "";
            resultTextBlock.Text = "";
        }

        private void checkAnswerButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (activeQuiz.CheckAnswer(answerTextBox.Text))
            {
                resultTextBlock.Text = "Correct! Well done.";
                Uri soundsource = new Uri("ms-appx:///Sounds/right.wav");
                soundMediaElement.Source = soundsource;
                soundMediaElement.Play();
            }
            else
            {
                resultTextBlock.Text = "Sorry, that is not correct.";
                Uri soundsource = new Uri("ms-appx:///Sounds/wrong.wav");
                soundMediaElement.Source = soundsource;
                soundMediaElement.Play();
            }
        }
    }
```

If some of you guys could tell me which code do I need to plug into event handler for `CheckAnswerButton_Click` so that it changes the background of the Grid, to `SKV_8915_s.jpg`, that would be super amazing!

Comment: This should theoretically be possible by setting the `Grid.Background` to an `ImageBrush`, but I myself have had a hard time getting it to work like this answer says https://stackoverflow.com/a/14085305/9363973

Comment: Hi @SSJ5Broli if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Answer (score 0):

> As you can see the Grid uses an Image called kingscross.jpg for it's background. I'm trying to make it so that the click on button Next Answer will cause Grid background to change to an Image called SKV_8915_s.jpg.

For your requirement, you could set `ImageBrush` for the Background property for Grid ,then bind the `ImageSource` with bool property like the follow. And use the converter to pass different image for each bool type.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="{x:Bind Resault,Converter={StaticResource IMConverter},Mode=OneWay}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
    </Grid.Background>
    <Button Content="Check" Click="Button_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

**Code Behind**

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
    private bool _resault;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void onPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public bool Resault
    {
        get => _resault;
        set
        {
            _resault = value;
            onPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Resault = !Resault;
    }
}
public class ImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return (bool)value ? new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/bc1.jpg")) : new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/bc2.jpg"));
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And I have post the [code sample](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/ChangeBackgroundTest) to github that you could refe.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip, but at this point this solution would be above my head, I am not familiar with resault. But instead I found an easy way to do it by going into XAML preview window and creating new image element imgbg2. Then it would let me change it from the code behind like such:

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the tip, but at this point this solution would be above my head, I am not familiar with resault. But instead I found an easy way to do it by going into XAML preview window and creating new image element imgbg2. Then it would let me change it from the code behind like such:

```
  public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();           
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Brush newBackgroundBrushRed = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);           

            if (grid1.Background == newBackgroundBrushImage)
            {
                grid1.Background = bgimg2brush;
            }
else
            {
                grid1.Background = newBackgroundBrushImage;
            }
```